# how create split window animation like reeder(macOS) app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, animation

Reeder app in macOS has great interactive.
But how create split window animation like reeder(macOS) app?

Reeder macOS client screenshot:

[image: Reeder macOS client screenshot]

thank you for your answer. i really appreciate that.

Comment: As far as I know, this is all custom. You need to write your own split view and add the gesture controls

Comment: thanks for your comment, @mangerlahn